# Bundle keys/values stored in android service disappear in Message

Tags: android

My activity shares the Handler around the app to worker threads in a service. Threads use the handler to sendMessage() Acitivity use handleMessage() to handle them

The Activity goes to background Android kills it and when come back it is started again.

The Activity calls Service's static method to check the last status (as to what the last sendMessage() was ) of threads in service. So that it can init its UI status based on the service thread's last message

```
Message m = SyncService.lastSyncMessage();
```

**For some reason the bundle inside the message m is sometimes valid (contains key/value pairs) and sometimes key/values are absent**

The code on the side of thread which forwards message to UI via handler looks like this.

```
  Handler uiHandler = UIGlobals.getHandler();
  Message msg = uiHandler.obtainMessage();
  Bundle msgBundle = new Bundle();

  msgBundle.putInt("status", syncEv.status.ordinal());
  msgBundle.putString("param", syncEv.param);

  msg.setData(msgBundle);
  if(uiHandler.sendMessage(msg))
  {
    lastMessage = msg;
  }
```

The static method in the service

```
   public static Message lastSyncMessage()
{
    return lastMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Message object came from pool. When Activity is gone, handler's callback points to unavailable object. Android seem to re-prepare the Message ref for usage in the Pool, 
To solve it I stored the Actual Event in the static member rather than the Message.